# Using fetch to change form method to DELETE

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send a form with the DELETE method from a twig template to my PHP controller and I know I have to use the fetch API, but I cannot seem to do it correctly and I don't really understand why. I don't need to send any information since everything is being handled in the PHP part, I just need the form to be of method DELETE. Here is the snippet of code I'm using to send the form:

```
<form>
       <input onclick="fetch('profile/deleteProfile', {method: 'DELETE'})" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

I've tried giving the URL to the fetch method to where the info is and then changing the method to DELETE, the result is the PHP function not activating and I only get a "?" at the end of the url when I click the button

Comment: Because the form is being submitted when you click the submit button. No `method` attribute is set, so GET will be used. What is your question?

Comment: @Bergi I don't think delete has made it into the html standards yet - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `submit` is triggered, it immediately submits the form unless an `onclick` handler returns false or the event's default behaviour is prevented.

`fetch` is an asynchronous/promise-based function, so usually it either needs to be `await`ed or chained using `.then()`.

However, as you are calling `fetch` in the `onclick` handler for your `submit`, the submit is triggering normally and the `fetch` does not get to run properly.

If you wish to send a `DELETE` request then you don't need a form or a submit button. You should also prefer to use event listeners instead of adding Javascript directly into attributes, although there are times where this is necessary.

## Solution 1

Change your HTML to this (as in, remove the `form` tags too)

```
<button type="button" id="delete">Delete</button>
```

... and add a `script` tag at the bottom containing this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch('profile/deleteProfile', {
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).then(res => alert("Done"));
});
</script>
```

This will add an event listener for the button's click event, send your fetch request (observable in the `Network` tab of your browser), and then show an alert when the request has finished.

## Solution 2

This is only for if you *need* to leave your HTML as-is, and to just update the `onclick` attribute

```
<form>
    <input onclick="fetch('profile/deleteProfile', {method: 'DELETE'}); return false;" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

DELETE should be 'DELETE' - it is a string.

Comment: Already edited that, must have been a miswriting from my side, I did do it that way

Comment: Answers shouldn't be used to point out typo's or non-reproducible code. There is a special close flag for this.